# Show that the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix have modulus $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, unitary-matrices

> Show that the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix have modulus $1$.

I know that a unitary matrix can be defined as a square complex matrix $A$, such that

$$AA^*=A^*A=I$$

where $A^*$ is the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) of $A$, and $I$ is the identity matrix. Furthermore, for a square matrix $A$, the eigenvalue equation is expressed by $$Av=\lambda v$$

If I use the relationship $u v=v^*u$ and take the conjugate transpose of this equation then
$$v^*A^*=\lambda^*v^*$$

But now I got stuck. Can someone help?

Comment: i think you can find your answer in part 4 of this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40246/matrices-hermitian-and-unitary

Comment: I actually looked at that post but it was difficult to understand. I think they do it in another way.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You multiply your two relations to obtain

\begin{align}
v^*A^*Av &=\lambda^* v^*\lambda v \\
v^*Iv &=\left(\lambda^*\lambda\right) v^*v \\
v^*v &=\left(\lambda^*\lambda\right) v^*v \\
||v||^2 &= |\lambda|^2 ||v||^2 \\
\sqrt{1} &=|\lambda| \\
1 &=|\lambda|
\end{align}

---

Recall that the [modulus of a complex number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html) $\lambda = a + bi$, also called the "complex norm", is denoted $|\lambda|$ and defined by $|\lambda| = |a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\lambda^*\lambda = (a -bi)(a + bi) = a^2 + b^2$. Hence $\lambda^*\lambda = |\lambda|^2.$

Comment: Why is the negative square root in the end neglected ? Shouldn’t it be $\lambda =+1,-1$

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it is beacause a modulus is always positive

Comment: Very good proof! However, an interesting thing is that you can perhaps stop at the third last step, because an equivalent condition of a unitary matrix is that its eigenvector lies on the unit circle, so therefore, has magnitude 1.

Answer (score 12):

A unitary matrix $U$ preserves the inner product:   $\langle Ux, Ux\rangle =\langle x,U^*Ux\rangle =\langle x,x\rangle $.

Thus if $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue,  $Ux=\lambda x$, we get $\vert\lambda \vert^2\langle x,x\rangle =\langle \lambda x,\lambda x\rangle =\langle Ux, Ux\rangle =\langle x,x\rangle $.

So $\vert \lambda\vert^2=1\implies \vert \lambda\vert=1$.

Comment: Why is the negative square root in the end neglected ? Shouldn’t it be $\lambda =+1,-1$

Comment: @Shashaank The modulus is always nonnegative.

Comment: $|\lambda|=1$ implies that $\lambda$ lies on the unit circle. @Shashaank

Answer (score 4):

$\Delta$ as $\lambda$

$Av=\Delta v$

$(Av)^*=(\Delta v)^*$

$v^*A^*=\Delta^*v^*$

$v^*A^*Av=\Delta^*v^*\Delta v$

As $A^*A=I$

$v^*Iv=\Delta^*\Delta v^*v$

$v^*v=\Delta^*\Delta v^*v$

$(1-\Delta^*\Delta)v^*v=0$

Since $v$ is not equal to zero.

Hence

$1-\Delta\Delta^*=0\implies \Delta^*\Delta=1$

$|\Delta|^2=1\implies |\Delta|=1$.

Comment: What was the point changing $\lambda$ to $\Delta$? See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for help formatting in MathJax.

Comment: I've added formatting to your answer, hope that's ok. Note that two * format as italic in HTML which was why some stuff rendered funny..

Answer (score 2):

The result that you seek follows from the following.

**Lemma**. If $A$ is unitary and $\vert \vert x \vert \vert_2 = 1$, then $\vert\vert Ax \vert\vert_2 =1$.

*Proof*. By definition, 
$$ \vert\vert Ax \vert\vert_2^2 =\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = (Ax)^*(Ax) = x^*A^*A x = x^*x = \vert\vert x \vert\vert_2^2 = 1.$$

---

If $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair of $A$, then, without loss of generality, it may be assumed that $\vert\vert v \vert\vert_2 = 1$. Following the lemma above and the absolute homogeneity property of vector norms, notice that 
$$ |\lambda| 
= |\lambda|\vert\vert v \vert\vert_2 
= \vert\vert \lambda v \vert\vert_2 
= \vert\vert Av \vert\vert_2
= 1,$$
as desired.