# Norm of a skew symmetric unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a unitary matrix, $U$ can be nonsymmetric, its eigenvalues can be complex numbers and all have modulus $1$.

Is there an upper bound for the maximum **singular value of its skew symmetric part** (which is not necessarily unitary) depending on its eigenvalues?

i.e.: Is there an $f$ such that
$\left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right) \le  f\left(\lambda_i\left(U\right)\right)$ ?

More details:

Observe that if $U=I$ (eigenvalues are real) $\Rightarrow \left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right) = 0$, and if $U$ is skew-symmetric (eigenvalues purely imaginary) $\Rightarrow\left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right) = 1$. Therefore there is a relationship between the norm $\left\|\frac{U - U^T}{2} \right\|_2 = \sigma_\text{max}\left(\frac{U - U^T}{2}\right)$ and the argument of the eigenvalues of $U$, i.e. $f\left(\lambda_i\left(U\right)\right) = f\left(\text{arg}(\lambda_i\left(U\right))\right)$.

Further notes: in my work $U$ is the unitary factor of the polar decomposition of an M-matrix, but this may be irrelevant.

Comment: Your question is confusing: you say "unitary" (usually used in complex matrices) but consider $U^T$ which makes me think that you consider $U$ real. If $U$ is real, the only possible eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717713/show-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-unitary-matrix-have-modulus-1

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for your interest! In my case $U$ is real, but unitary does not imply symmetric. When $U$ is nonsymmetric, its eigenvalues are complex numbers (regardless of the matrix being real) and they lie at the unit circle in the complex plane. I am looking for a relationship between the maximum **singular value** of the **skew-symmetric part** of $U$ (not necessarily unitary) and the eigenvalues of $U$.

Comment: @dantopa Thanks for the link! But I am looking for a relationship between the maximum **singular value** of the **skew-symmetric part** of $U$ (not necessarily unitary) and the eigenvalues of $U$ here. How do I use the fact of the eigenvalues having modulus 1?

Comment: I think your norm should be the $\infty$-norm, not the $2$-norm (seeing as you want the maximum singular value).

Comment: @John Thanks for your answer! No, the $\infty$ norm is the maximum absolute row sum of the matrix. The 2-norm **is** the maximum singular value. Check [the Wikipedia article for matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Comment: @Astor: whatever Wikipedia says, that naming doesn't agree with practice in all areas of math I know. It is true that $\|\cdot\|_\infty $ is used for (at least) three different norms, but $\|\cdot\|_2$ for the operator norm is unusual and confusing. And, by the way, that same article uses $\|\cdot\|_2$ in the usual way, for the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for the clarification, our areas of math seem to be disjoint then. Do you think you could navigate through the awful, awful $\|\cdot\|_2$ notation to address the actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unitary is normal, so it is diagonalizable by unitary conjugation. So we can think of $U $ diagonal, with the eigenvalues as the diagonal entries. The imaginary part is then the diagonal matrix of the imaginary parts of the eigenvalues. So
$$
\left\|\frac {U-U^*}2\right\|=\max\{|\text {Im}\,\lambda_j|:\ j=1,\ldots,n\}. $$

Comment: Are you assuming that the maximum singular value is equal to the spectral radius of $\frac{U - U^T}{2}$? Why?

Comment: Also, I wrote $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, so I probably should have said "orthogonal" not unitary. My apologies.

Comment: To the spectral radius of $\frac {U-U^*}{2i} $, yes. Because it is selfadjoint. But you don't even need that.  In a diagonal matrix, you can calculate the singular values explicitly.