# Bound on eigenvalues of $A+A^*$ for $A$ unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ complex unitary matrix. I want to show that the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the matrix $A+A^{\star}$ are real numbers that satisfy the relation $-2 \leq \lambda \leq 2$.

I have looked up the definitions and I read that a unitary matrix is a square matrix for which $AA^{+}=I$.

(The transpose matrix of $A^{\star}$ is symbolized with $A^{+}$.)

($A^{\star}$: complex conjugate)

In order to show that the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the matrix $A+A^{\star}$ are real numbers and satisfy that $-2 \leq \lambda \leq 2$, do we maybe have to find the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A+A^{\star}$ ? If so, how? Is there a relation? Or do we have to do it somehow else?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717713/show-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-unitary-matrix-have-modulus-1

Comment: @RozaTh You should read the question first.

Comment: Evinda Your definition of "unitary" is incorrect. A matrix is unitary if $AA^* = I$. Here, $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$, i.e., the transpose with each entry conjugated.

Comment: @amsmath A ok. And how can we find a relation for the eigenvalues?

Comment: Is $A^\star$ just the complex conjugate or the hermitian conjugate (i.e. transpose of complex conjugate)? Your definitions of $A^\star$ and $A^+$ are confusing.

Comment: @Christoph Read my comment. The stuff in the question is definitely wrong.

Comment: @amsmath If $A^+$ is the hermitian conjugate, the definitions in the question are at least not contradictory. I guess the statement about $A+\overline A$ doesn't hold, but I didn't think about a counter example.

Comment: @Christoph Uhh aahhh. Sorry. My bad. Usually, $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose and not just the conjugate. So, my answer does not refer to the problem as stated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following I let $A^*$ denote the *complex conjugate transpose* of $A$ and by $\overline A$ just the complex conjugate.

The original statement about $A+\overline A$ in the question is false. Just take $A = (\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{smallmatrix})$ which is unitary. Then $A+\overline A = 2A$ which has eigenvalues $\pm 2i$.

Let us prove that the statement holds for $A+A^*$. You may want to prove first as an exercise that $A$ unitary implies that $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$ for each vector $x$.

Now, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A+A^*$ with eigenvector $x$. We may assume WLOG that $\|x\|=1$. Then (since for all vectors $y,z$ we have $(A^*y,z) = (y,Az) = \overline{(Az,y)}$)
\begin{align*}
\lambda
&= (\lambda x,x) = (Ax+A^*x,x) = (Ax,x) + (A^*x,x)\\
&= (Ax,x)+(x,Ax) = 2\operatorname{Re}(Ax,x).
\end{align*}
In particular, $\lambda$ is real. Now, this implies
$$
|\lambda|\le 2|(Ax,x)|\le 2\|Ax\|\|x\| = 2\|Ax\| = 2\|x\| = 2.
$$

Comment: So we get that $|\lambda|=2$ which implies that $\lambda=\pm 2$. And thus $\lambda$ is real and $-2 \leq \lambda \leq 2$, right? @amsmath

Comment: Or could it also be that $\lambda$ takes also other values, since it could be complex? @amsmath

Comment: I edited my answer. So, $\lambda$ is real and $|\lambda|\le 2$ means $-2\le\lambda\le 2$.

Comment: Why does it hold that $(Ax,x)+(x,Ax)=2Re(Ax,x)$ ? @amsmath

Comment: Because for each complex number $w$ we have $w+\overline w = 2Re(w)$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot :)