# Prove that all complex eigenvalues of the operators of a unitary or orthogonal representation have modulus 1.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory, orthogonal-matrices

The question is given below:

> Let $T$ be an orthogonal or unitary representation of the group $G$. Prove that all complex eigenvalues of the operators $T(g)$, $g \in G$ have modulus one.

But I do not know how the answer of it will differ from the answer given in this link:

[Show that the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix have modulus $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717713/show-that-the-eigenvalues-of-a-unitary-matrix-have-modulus-1)

And what are the relations between operators of orthogonal or unitary representation and unitary or orthogonal matrices?

Comment: That's weird: from your previous questions, it's clear that you can use MathJax, yet you still embedded the question in an image? Please format all questions in text and MathJax as much as possible, to help people search for your question.

Comment: Okay I am sorry @TheoBendit I will obey this rule as much as possible.

Comment: No worries. Images are primarily used to embed diagrams, or other things that might aid understanding that cannot be formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An orthogonal representation is a representation by orthogonal matrices. A unitary representation is a representation by unitary matrices. So it really is just a question about eigenvalues of such matrices.

Comment: So you mean that the answer to the above question is the same as the answer in the link mentioned above?

Comment: Well, the *question* is the same as the one in the link. I haven't visited the link to see what the answer there says.

Answer (score 1):

An orthogonal operator $A : X\rightarrow X$ on an inner product space $X$ satisfies $\|Ax\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$. If $A$ were to have an eigenvector $x\neq 0$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\|\lambda x\|=\|x\|$ or $|\lambda|\|x\|=\|x\|$ would have to hold, which would force $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: So you are saying that the above link  does not contain the answer?